# Can I set aws S3 policy for cloudflare?

Tags: amazon-s3, cloudflare

I have a S3 Bucket names **"cdn.myexmaple.com"**

and I set Cloudflare point my site "myexample.com" DNS

```
CNAME cdn cdn.myexample.com.s3.amazonaws.com
```

how can I set my bucket policy allow Cloudflare can get bucket object?

There is a way to set S3 Bucket allow http refer like:

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Id":"http referer policy example",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"Allow get requests originated from www.example.com and example.com",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal":"*",
      "Action":"s3:GetObject",
      "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::cdn.myexample.com/*",
      "Condition":{
        "StringLike":{
          "aws:Referer":[
            "http://cdn.myexample.com/*",
            "http://www.myexample.com/*"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Can I set a police that allow CLoudFlare to access object?

Comment: CloudFlare doesn't work with the above example ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have tips for [S3 and CloudFlare](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168926-How-do-I-use-CloudFlare-with-Amazon-s-S3-Service-) already.

Everything should work fine as long as we are proxying the record in your DNS settings.

Comment: OMG~ Thank you very much!! I got it!

Comment: @damoncloudflare does this continue to work if public getObject is restricted to referrer like above? Or is there a specific link that needs to happen there?

Comment: How about blocking request directly to my s3 bucket (not via cloudflare)?